# Call Rspec Method from Rakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rake

I am trying to write a rake test that needs to call a method in another file in order to set up my current session, but when I try to include the filepath at the top of my rake file I get this Error:

```
rake aborted!LoadError: cannot load such file -- ~/../../spec/models/run_spec.rb
```

My rakefile is as follows:

```js
require 'sqlite3'
require 'optparse'
require '~/../../spec/models/run_spec.rb'

task refresh_gn_input_files: :environment do
     LOANS_INPUT_PATH_GN = Rails.root.to_s +
       '/spec/inputs/loans_input_gn.json'
     PRICING_INPUT_PATH_GN = Rails.root.to_s +
       '/spec/inputs/pricing_input_gn.json'
 
     puts 'creating and configuring current session...'
     create_and_configure_session
 
     puts 'generating loans input file...'
     puts "THIS IS THE TEST: #{@session}"
 
     puts 'geerating pricing input file...'
   end
```

So I want to be able to call this 'create_and_configure_session' method that I have in another file but I am not able to include it in my rakefile?

Path to rakefile: ~/Desktop/a/spec/models/run_spec.rb

Path to outside method: ~/Desktop/a/lib/tasks/a_tasks_rake

Method code:

```js
def create_and_configure_session 
  @support_engine = M::ScriptSet.new.get_engine("Support")
  ...
end
```

Comment: Seems strange that you'd want your test and application code to leak into each other... I imagine this would be a flag that you need to refactor something. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you tried, you are going up two levels(with `..`) from `~`.

On a Mac that would land you in `/`.

Either of these should get you to your file:

```
require_relative '../../spec/models/run_spec'
require '~/Desktop/a/spec/models/run_spec'
```

Comment: thanks I figured it out my problem now is I cant use my method in my spec file since it requires 'spec_helper' which is used with rspec when called from the root. I am trying to create a separate class instead